# How to hide inside app icon on android marshmallow?

Tags: android

I use marshmallow android.
I want inside app. `Camera,Setting,internet...` hide icon.

I know how to hide icon on kitkat android.

but I don't know how to hide icon on marshmallow.

how to hide app icon on android marshmallow?

Answer (score 2):

use below code along with Package manager permission

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, com.apps.MainActivity.class); // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: This should work, I was playing around once and this few lines did it.

Comment: @Akash Dubey  thanks, this code android internal app hide possible?